# How to stop velocity animation repeating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I am using velocity to animate a scroll button for a website. When the window is scrolled the button animates changing position and when we reach again the top, it returns where it was. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mustSlideRight = true;
    var mustSlideLeft = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scrolledHeight = ($(window).scrollTop());

        if (scrolledHeight > 2 && mustSlideRight)  {

            $(".scrollButton")
                .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px"}, {duration: 200, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({width: "0px", height: "0px", opacity: "0"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({left: "95%", backgroundPosition: "-50px"}, {duration: 1})
                .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px", opacity: "1"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({width: "50px", height: "50px"}, {duration: 150, easing: "ease-in-out"});
            mustSlideRight = false;
            mustSlideLeft = true;
        }
        else if (scrolledHeight < 10 && mustSlideLeft) {

            $(".scrollButton")
                .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px"}, {duration: 200, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({width: "0px", height: "0px", opacity: "0"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({left: "49%", backgroundPosition: "0px"}, {duration: 1})
                .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px", opacity: "1"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                .velocity({width: "50px", height: "50px"}, {duration: 150, easing: "ease-in-out"});
            mustSlideLeft = false;
            mustSlideRight = true;
        }
    });
```

The background image of the button is a sprite.

The problem is that the animation runs many times back and forth. Going down it runs three times and going back up it runs 5-6 times. I think that there is a problem with how i wrote the code, in the logic of it, but i cant figure it out. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

@mattmokary : I did what you proposed but things got worse, even though I have the feeling that this is the way. However I'm almost sure that I have an error in my code. The animation doesn't start at all.

```
 var mustSlideRight = true;
    var mustSlideLeft = false;
    var animating = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if (animating){
            return;
        }else if (!animating){
            animating = true;
            var scrolledHeight = ($(window).scrollTop());

            if (scrolledHeight > 2 && mustSlideRight)  {

                $(".scrollButton")
                    .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px"}, {duration: 200, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({width: "0px", height: "0px", opacity: "0"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({left: "95%", backgroundPosition: "-50px"}, {duration: 1})
                    .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px", opacity: "1"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({width: "50px", height: "50px"}, {duration: 150, complete: function(){animating = false;}, easing: "ease-in-out"});
                mustSlideRight = false;
                mustSlideLeft = true;
            }
            else if (scrolledHeight < 10 && mustSlideLeft) {

                $(".scrollButton")
                    .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px"}, {duration: 200, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({width: "0px", height: "0px", opacity: "0"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({left: "49%", backgroundPosition: "0px"}, {duration: 1})
                    .velocity({width: "55px", height: "55px", opacity: "1"}, {duration: 80, easing: "ease-in-out"})
                    .velocity({width: "50px", height: "50px"}, {duration: 150, complete: function(){animating = false;}, easing: "ease-in-out"});
                mustSlideLeft = false;
                mustSlideRight = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried debouncing the animation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was much easier than i thought. i just changed the parameters in the if statements to trigger the animations only to very specific points and the animation doesn't repeat ;)

```
if($(document).scrollTop() >= 3 && mustSlideRight) {
}else if ($(document).scrollTop() <=2 && mustSlideLeft){}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll down a page, many `scroll` events are fired. This function gets called once for each event, with the animations getting queued up.

To fix it, add a flag signifying that an animation is already running, and don't run any more animations while that flag is `true`. Something like:

```
var animating = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
     if (animating) {
         return;
     }

     // ...
});
```

You'll also have to set `animating = true` when you do perform animations, and pass a callback to velocity to run after the animation completes that sets `animating = false`.